# How to calculate "midpoint date" by group in Stata?

Tags: date, time, stata

I have a dataset with two variables: `journalistName`, `articleDate`

For each journalist (group),  I want to create a variable that chronologically categorizes the articles into `1` for "first half" and `2` for "second half".

For example, if a journalist wrote 4 articles, I want first two articles categorized as `1`.

If he wrote 5 articles, I want first three articles categorized as `1`.

One possibility I thought of is to calculate the midpoint date and then use if condition (`gen cat1 = 1 if midpoint > startdate`) but I dont know how to generate such midpoint in Stata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per your description of which articles to categorize as `1`, you're looking for the midpoint of the *number of articles* rather than the midpoint of the *date range*.

One solution is to use `by` group processing, `_n`, and `_N`:

```
gen cat = 2
bysort author (date): replace cat = 1 if _n <= ceil(_N/2)
```

This sorts by `author` and `date`, and then assigns `cat = 1` to observations within each group of `author` where the current observation (`_n`) number is less than or equal to the median observation (`ceil(_N/2)`).

Note that you need a numeric (rather than string) date for the sort to work properly. Also, in my opinion, `cat = {1,2}` is less intuitive than something like `firsthalf = {0,1}`. Either way, labeling the values (`help label`) would aid clarity.

For more information, see `help by` and [this article](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=pr0004).

Finally, the method in action:

```
clear all
input str10 author str10 datestr
"Alex" "09may2015"
"Alex" "06apr2015"
"Alex" "15jul2014"
"Alex" "19aug2013"
"Alex" "03mar2009"
"Betty" "09may2015"
"Betty" "06apr2015"
"Betty" "15jul2014"
"Betty" "19aug2013"
end

gen date = daily(datestr, "DMY")
format date %td

gen cat = 2
bysort author (date): replace cat = 1 if _n <= ceil(_N/2)

list , sepby(author) noobs
```

and the result

```
  +--------------------------------------+
  | author     datestr        date   cat |
  |--------------------------------------|
  |   Alex   03mar2009   03mar2009     1 |
  |   Alex   19aug2013   19aug2013     1 |
  |   Alex   15jul2014   15jul2014     1 |
  |   Alex   06apr2015   06apr2015     2 |
  |   Alex   09may2015   09may2015     2 |
  |--------------------------------------|
  |  Betty   19aug2013   19aug2013     1 |
  |  Betty   15jul2014   15jul2014     1 |
  |  Betty   06apr2015   06apr2015     2 |
  |  Betty   09may2015   09may2015     2 |
  +--------------------------------------+
```

---

If you are indeed seeking to calculate the midpoint date, you can do so using the same general principle:

```
bysort author (date): gen beforemiddate = date <= ceil((date[_N] + date[1]) / 2)
```

---

Also, to find the last date in the "pre-midpoint" period, you can use the same principles:

```
bysort author cat (date): gen lastdate = date[_N] if cat == 1
by author: replace lastdate = lastdate[_n-1] if missing(lastdate)
format lastdate %td
```

or an `egen` function with a logical test included gets the job done a bit faster:

```
egen lastdate = max(date * (cat == 1)) , by(author)
format lastdate %td
```

Comment: Thanks. It works for the purpose of categorizing the articles. But if I still want the date of the last article in category 1 (by journalist), is there away to extract that info out?

Comment: Good advice. The main idea could be one line: 
`bysort author (date): gen cat = 1 +  (_n > ceil(_N/2))`